# Failed to connect to FTP Server on XAMPP (Mac)

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, xampp, localhost

I have installed xampp and wordpress, which I run on my local host. When I try to make changes, eg. remove plugins it keeps asking me for the following:

```
hostname
FTP username
FTP password
```

I know the username and the password but I don't know what to type in hostname. I tried "localhost" or path to the actual wp Wordpress folder (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projects/wp)- both don't work.

**Please note that I have granted all permissions to this user. I feel that the hostname I put is wrong.**

Can you please help me out with this? I'm stuck on this (I guess) basic step and can't do anything more.

Comment: What is that "it" that asks you for that stuff?

Comment: @NicoHaase it's Wordpress.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, go to wp-config.php and add this line **after** the

@package WordPress

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

then open the Terminal and paste this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/
```

followed by your system password

Done and done!

Comment: work for me, nice bro

Answer (score 1):

A  [usefull video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSfJsI1Hqeo&ab_channel=diomugo) about installing Xampp correctly.

Change in your php.ini after

@package Wordpress

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

And change your directory to 777 and the files to 644 in your terminal:

```
sudo find /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo find /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Please add all relevant information to your answer instead of linking to external sites

Comment: the 127.0.0.1 doesn't work. THe same with the actual IP which is displayed in xampp which is 192.168.64.2. Still nothing :(